# Keep the history of the user on one web-site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, backbone.js

I know there are few posts on this topic

However what I would like to rise the topic in slightly different way:

How do I know that the user is coming back from a particular page, say `/product_pages/3`

I use backbone for the part, where I would like to track users history, that is built on top of RoR application. The reason I would like to know if the user is coming back from a particular page is to keep the backbone form populated with the values user entered initially, however if the user comes from other pages, say `/provider_pages/14`, then I would like to clear the form values.

Solutions tried:

HTML5 history is not persistent across browsers (even between FF and Chrome) and as tried it is not the best solution for this issue;
Backbone history doesn't do the trick, as it tracks only Backbone application, whenever a user steps out of backbone app, Backbone.history loses the state;
RoR request also is not a solution, assuming that most of the users will click back button to return to form / search results, and 'back' button doesn't trigger a new request :)

So I am slightly puzzled with the solution for this issue.

Here are the bits of code:

The form:

```
<ul id="formfields">
    <li>
        <label>Driver type
        <select id="driver-type" name="driver-type" class="ddl jqrequired">
            options...
        </select></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Postcode
        <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode_with_suburbs" style="width:207px" class="jqrequired postcode-with-suburb"></label>
    </li>
    <li id="date_insurance_required_section">
        <label>Date insurance required
        <input type="text" name="date_insurence_required" id="date_insurance_required" style="width:207px" class="jqrequired"></label>
        <span style="display:none;" id="renewalDate"></span>
    </li>
    <li id="car-insurers-section">
        <label>Your current car insurer (if applicable)
        <input type="text" id="car-insurers" style="width:220px" class="ddl clearfix" class="jqrequired" placeholder="Please enter current insurer">
        </label>
    </li>
    etc etc etc.....
```

Setting the values on the backbone side via fetch request: `and I assume here is the place where I need to keep track of users that are coming back`

```
$("#car-insurers").val(results.Insurer);
$("#renewal_date").val(results.RenewalDate);
$("#date_insurence_required").val(results.InsuranceRequired);
$("#renewal-type").val(results.RenewalType);
$("#renewal-amount").val(results.RenewalAmount);
$("#driver-type").select2("val", results.DriverType);
$("#postcode_with_suburbs").val(results.Postcode);
$("#email").val(results.EmailAddress);
if (results.EmailSend == "on") {
    $('#email-consent').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

some hint,

- write last path->timestamp to cookie for each access from your server.
- write access history to localStorage(most of the modern browsers support this feature)

Comment: I liked the idea about localStorage